# Azure Data Factory Web Activity save output

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

Is there a way to save the output of an Azure Data Factory Web Activity into a dataset?

Here is my current use case:

1. I have to dynamically build a JSON post request
2. The API I'm trying to reach requires a SSL certificate so I have to use the Web Activity **Authentication** Client Certificate option.
3. The API also requires basic authentication so I input the Content -Type and authorization guid in the header section of the Web Activity.
4. Once I get the JSON response from my post request I need to save the response into a blob storage some where.

I tried using the Copy Data Set HTTPS or Rest API as a data set source but both only allow one type of authentication certificate or Basic authentication.

Is there a way I can configure the Rest API or HTTPS data set source handle both types of authentications (SSL and Basic Authorization) or capture all the Web Activity output into a blob storage?

Thank you all for your help! I'm desperate at the moment lol..

Here is what my Web Activity looks like (sorry I had hide part of the credentials for security purposes:
[image: Web Activity]

Answer (score 0):

Please use Http dataset in your Coput Activity.

When we create the linked service of the Http dataset, select **client certificate** option and embedded data, then we need to upload the SSL certificate.

[image]

The offical document is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-http#linked-service-properties).

Comment: Hi Joseph, Thank you for your detailed answer. I tried your example the only problem is there a way I can flatten the JSON afterwards? I should have put this in my use case before. Once I have the data stored some where I need to flatten the JSON afterwards in a csv format. The copy activity is making me cast the JSON output to a string. Then the back slashes are added. When I got to the data flow piece to flatten the fields the file needs its json arrays defined.

Comment: Copy JSON into Blob Storage seems to be some problems.We can consider about copying it into local or Azure SQL Server. You can see my another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64226508/azure-data-factory-copy-json-to-a-row-in-a-table/64315339#64315339).But local  SQL Server is not supported as data source in  dataflow.

Comment: Unfortunately the data returned back is so large we need to store into blob storage some where. Do you know is a way in a REST source or HTTPS to input both a SSL certificate and Basic Authentication? If had a way of doing that would probably make it easier to put the json in blob storage.